# what is the workflow when refresh token expired or invalid

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I am using auth 2.0 to design an api（Resource Owner Password Credentials Model）, now I was wonder if the refresh token expired or invalid, what should the client do? the client redirect to the login page or just invoke the get refresh token api with appId&appSecret and refresh token silently?

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of points that you must take in concideration before designing your api:

The resource owner password credentials :

- All what clients need is to send the client_id/client_secret with the username/password/scopes to the endpoint /token of the identiy provider (IDP) to get a token;
- This type of grant is used for the server to server connection;
- It should not be used in the case of user authentication or to authenticate a web applications;
- If the token is expired the client must refresh the token to get new access_token, by using the same endpoint /token with the refresh_token got from the previous call in params to the IDP

If your IDP accept the refresh token you need to send a request with thoses parametres:

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token' \
--header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data grant_type=refresh_token \
--data 'client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID' \
--data refresh_token=YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN
```

If not you can do a request to renew the token like the first time.

Now for your question the refresh token will never be expire if the flow is correctly implemented and this is how it work:

- First the client submit for an access_token and in the response he got the access_token and refresh_token;
- Before the access_token is expired the client need to make a request with refresh_token to get a new access_token; and in the response we have also  new refresh_token, so the client need to update refresh_token with the latest one;

Comment: I found some api not design like that, when they refresh the access token, they only passed the refresh token to the server side, did not pass any other parameter, are the action is a good practice? @GAOUL

Comment: I have update my response to unswer your question

Comment: OP asked about the case when `refresh token` expired, however, you're talking about the point to refresh the `access token` on expiration using the existing refresh token.

Comment: I have update my unswer, thanks

Comment: there still a problem, if the user have a long time did not use the app(for example, the user did not use the app for 9 month), one day she open the app, the refresh token and access token both expired, how to handle this? tell user to login? @GAOUL

Comment: when the access_token and refresh_token are expired that mean the client cannot connect to the application he need to authenticate again

Answer (score 1):

In case `refresh token` expired, the fresh flow should be initiated where resouce owner will provide their credentials details to the client. Also, this grant type should only be used where `resouce owner` has a highly trust relationship with the client, obviously owner is sharing their credentials with the client.