# why the refresh token set 10 years to expire when design the app auth specification

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am design the app auth api with auth2.0, now I found some companies set the refresh token expire with 10 years! why design like that? it is a good practice? how long should I set the refresh token expire time?

I found the google oauth 2.0 refresh token never expired for native app: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because any answer will only be speculation

Comment: I did not downvote it @dolphin only voted to close. Someone else downvoted. Your first question is "why designed like that?".  This is not possible for us to answer, only to speculate on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how often you want to to force the user login again and reauthenticate.

In some system you want the user to do this more often and in a system with for example 10 years refresh token, you don't want the user to have to login again after the first successful authentication.

Comment: why do not refresh the refresh token by username and password? we should not store the username and passowrd?@Tore Nestenius

Comment: Because that is now how it works, the client application who receives the access/refresh token never sees the user username/password. and that is by design.

Comment: I do not think store the user password is a good idea. but if did not store the password, we should make the refresh token expire for very long time.@Tore Nestenius

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to set the liftime of refresh_token to 10 years like that you have a big security problem, the best implementation of refresh_token is when it is used the first time it should be revocked or a lifetime not much than access_token.
see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71448152/what-is-the-workflow-when-refresh-token-expired-or-invalid/71449041#71449041)

Comment: The service issuing the tokens can always "revoke/disable" existing refresh tokens if they have a security issue,.