# why all the app no need to login again when first login, how to do it like that with oauth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0

Recently I am learning oauth 2.0, and all the docs said that when the refresh token invalid or expired and let the user to relogin. To my experience to use the apps, no apps need to relogin again after the first login. how did they do that? store the username and password and refresh the refresh token with the username and password? set the refresh token for a long time(for example, set the refresh token 5 year to expired)?how did they do that?

Answer (score 0):

this is what we could silent refresh, when the client connects the first time, the token is refreshed in the background with the refresh token before the token expire, and for your refresh token, you don't need long lifetime you need just to keep the latest one.
see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71448152/what-is-the-workflow-when-refresh-token-expired-or-invalid/71449041#71449041)